# High performance graphical overlay on a YUV (UYVY) image (C++)

Tags: c++, rendering, yuv

**My requirements**: Overlay graphics (with alpha/antialiasing) onto a UYVY image as fast as possible. The rendering must take place in UYVY preferably because I need to to both render and encode (H.264 with ffmpeg).

What framework (perferablly cross-platform, but Windows only is OK) should I use to render the image to later render/encode?

I looked at openvc, and it seems the drawing happens in BGR, which would requirement to convert each frame from UYVY (2-channel) to BGR (3-channel), and then back again.

I looked at SDL, which uses hardware acceleration. It supports multiple textures with different color spaces. However, the method `SDL_RenderReadPixels`, which I would need to get the resulting composited image, mentions in the documentation "warning This is a very slow operation, and should not be used frequently."

Is there a framework that can draw onto a BYTE array of YUV, possible with alpha blending/anti-aliasing?

Comment: Most "fast" YUV (with hardware support) is stored as "lumps" of Y, then U, then V. So not in a linear form. Most hardware will support fast drawing of such surfaces. However, I think your problem is not one of software framework, but finding a combination of SW and HW that does what you want.

Comment: You can set up an OpenGL with  interop OpenCL / CUDA kernel where you pass in YUV values in a buffer, then compute the new texture output. The kernel converts the values on the fly for each pixel (storing it in RGB(A) format) so that it can be rendered. This can be done in parallel although some fiddling is required to find the correct synchro balance. FreeImage does not support it, but libyuv might be exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You also can convert YUV to BGRA. And then perform drawing operation with using of the format. BGRA is more convenient then BGR for drawing because every its pixel is equal to 32-bit integer. Naturally after drawing you have to convert backward BGRA to YUV.

There is a fast cross-platform C++ [library](http://simd.sourceforge.net/) which can perform these manipulations.